# Support searchable in overleaf V2 generated pdf

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

I wrote my paper using overleaf (V2) platform but Editor-in-Chief replied

> We are unable to process your manuscript file. Please make sure the
>   manuscript file is a "searchable" PDF files (i.e. and document as
>   opposed to an image file).

Could you please guide me to make the generated manuscript pdf file to be searchable.

Comment: Was the submitted paper a PDF or a `.tex`? Is the processing of the submission automated? Perhaps you had a full-page image and the process failed because of that. In general, the PDF output of OverLeaf produces something that's searchable.

Comment: It is an overleaf generated pdf, and I don't have a full-page image

Comment: Okay, well I can't replicate your issue, since any minimal example I create via Overleaf is searchable.

Comment: That is true, it is weird but I did receive this reply. However, I used an offline tool, namely MikTex to generate the PDF then submitted the paper again.